# gdata:write.fwf Issues With data.table

Tags: r, data.table, gdata

```
library(gdata)
library(data.table)


# data.table fails here, data.frame doesn't -------------
df <- data.table(
  a = c('asdfasdf','asdf','asdgasdgasdgasdg','sdg'),
  b = runif(4,0,1)
  )
write.fwf(df,"df.txt")
write.fwf(data.frame(df),"df.txt")


# data.table fails here, data.frame doesn't -------------
df <- data.table(
  a = c('asd','qwe','ert','dfg'),
  b = runif(4,0,1)
)
write.fwf(df,"df.txt")
write.fwf(data.frame(df),"df.txt")


# data.table does not fail here, nor does data.frame ----
df <- data.table(
  a = c(1,5,4,7),
  b = runif(4,0,1)
)
write.fwf(df,"df.txt")
write.fwf(data.frame(df),"df.txt")
```

The error message when i try to write out the data.table is something I'm unable to connect to what `write.fwf` should be doing -
`Error in setkey(ans, NULL) : 
  x may no longer be the character name of the data.table. The possibility was undocumented and has been removed.`

Does anybody know why?

Comment: [Filed here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=240&aid=5069&atid=975) - please let me know if I should add more information/details to help with your archiving and tracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[#5069](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=240&aid=5069&atid=975) that `gdata:::write.fwf` ended up with error (at times) when the argument is a data.table is now fixed in [v1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240)**.

To summarise the issue, when `[.data.table` is called from within a function (here `write.fwf`) in a package, it tries to identify if the package is data.table aware, and if not (in this case, it's not), it calls the equivalent `[.data.frame` method. And in your case, that lead to a character vector. And the next line called for a `setkey` operation on a vector (to set the key to NULL).

A simple fix was to check if the output from `[.data.frame` is still a `data.table` and if so set the key to NULL.

Thanks again for reporting.